# Reflux setState with a Callback

Tags: react-native, callback, setstate

EDIT AGAIN: Opened an issue with Reflux here: https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/issues/544

EDIT: Reflux setState does not provide any callback for setState. They require you to use the component lifecycle methods to ensure the state is set prior to running any code. If you ever need to use the reflux setState outside of a component, where you do not have lifecycle methods, you will not be guaranteed the state is set. This is due to how Reflux does their setState. It loops all listening components and calls those components' setState methods. If Reflux were refactored to wait until all the listening components' setState calls complete then call a callback passed into its own setState method, that may work, but it would likely require a large rework of Reflux. I have started using a singleton class to manage some of these variables, as they are fully outside the component lifecycle.

Can you use setState with a callback in ReactNative or is that only in React? I'm using the below syntax and the first debugger is hit, but the second debugger and console log never get hit.

EDIT: After digging some more, it seems this does not occur when using setting the state directly, but only when running it through a reflux store and/or not using a component.

See snack here: https://snack.expo.io/S1dm3eFoM

```
   debugger
    this.setState( 
          params, 
          () => {
            debugger
            console.log("CALLIN IT BACK")
          }
        )
```

Comment: It is working as expected, there is only difference in the `DOM rendering`, the rest is same as `ReactJS`. Can you post more code or a [snack demo](https://snack.expo.io/)?

Comment: @PritishVaidya I've added a snack and gathered some more info. This seems like unexpected behavior to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm the creator of Reflux's ES6 styled stores/component hookups. Hopefully I can shed some light on this for you.**

Here's the important points:

### 1) Reflux sets its store state immediately upon `setState` calls.

Reflux's store state doesn't have the same problems as React and doesn't need React's workaround (callback). You **are** guaranteed that your change is immediately reflected in the store's state, that's why there is not a callback. The very next line of code will reflect the store's new state.

tl;dr, no workaround is required.

```
// in Reflux stores this works
this.setState({foo:'foo'});
console.log(this.state.foo === 'foo') // true
this.setState({foo:'bar'});
console.log(this.state.foo === 'bar') // true
```

### 2) Stores can never depend upon components!

The idea that the `setState` would give a callback about when the dependent *components* have all updated their state is a **major** violation of the single most fundamental of all flux principles: 1 way data flow.

If your store requires knowledge about whether or not components are doing something then you are already doing it wrong, and all the problems you are experiencing are XY problems of fundamentally not following flux in the first place. 1-way data flow is a main flux principle.

And that principle exists for good reason. Flux doesn't require 1:1 mapping of store state properties to component state properties. You can map anything to anything, or even just use the store's state for the building blocks of how you will run your own logic to create completely new state properties on the components. For example having `loaded` and `transitioned` as separate properties in store state, but mapping to a `loadedAndTransitioned` property in one component, and a `notLoadedOrTransitioned` in another component via your own custom logic. That's a **hugely** powerful part of flux. But your suggestion would pretty much destroy all that, since Reflux can't map people's custom logic.

1-way data flow must be maintained; Store's must operate the same independently of what components utilize them. Without this, the power of flux falls apart!

*Store's listen to actions, components listen to stores, actions are called from wherever. All flux-based data flows from action -> store -> component only.*

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the library for the [**refluxjs**](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/tree/master/docs/stores) and the problem and the workaround are as mentioned below.

**Problem**

The library provides with a new instance of the `setState` which is not exactly similar to `ReactJS setState`, **which omits the callback** as mentioned in their code below.

**/dist/reflux.js**

```
proto.setState = function (obj) {
        // Object.assign(this.state, obj); // later turn this to Object.assign and remove loop once support is good enough
        for (var key in obj) {
            this.state[key] = obj[key];
        }
        // if there's an id (i.e. it's being tracked by the global state) then make sure to update the global state
        if (this.id) {
            Reflux.GlobalState[this.id] = this.state;
        }
        // trigger, because any component it's attached to is listening and will merge the store state into its own on a store trigger
        this.trigger(obj);
    };
```

Also as mentioned here in the docs

> That store will store its state on a `this.state` property, and mutate its `state` via `this.setState()` **in a way that is extremely similar to React classes themselves**.

**WorkAround**

The library provides with the `listener` functions, which provide us with the callbacks of the `setState` obj of the `ReactJS` as mentioned in the below snippet.

**/dist/reflux.js**

```
 componentDidMount: function() {
            var me = this;

            _.extend(me, ListenerMethods);

            this.listenTo(listenable, function(v) {
                me.setState(_.object([key],[v]));
            });
        },
```

You can use them in the following [way](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/tree/master/docs/stores#defining-stores)

```
this.listenTo(action, callback)
```

*Hope it clears the doubts*

**Edit:** 
Usage as per the [docs](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/tree/master/docs/stores)

**To listen inside of the store**

```
constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {count: 0};
        this.listenTo(increment, this.incrementItUp);
    }

incrementItUp()
    {
        var newCount = this.state.count + 1;
        this.setState({count: newCount});
    }
```

**To listen outside of the store anywhere**

```
// listen directly to an action
myActions.actionName.listen(myCallbackFunc);

// listen to a child action
myActions.load.completed.listen(myCallbackFunc);
```

> Here's the link to the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/SkkOJ_YoG) with working callbacks based on **Promises**

Comment: Well that makes sense then. In my example code though, I'm calling this from a static function in a helper class. Is there a way to do a workaround that doesn't involve having a component did mount, or a component at all?

Comment: Check the docs, you can bind the listener in the constructor itself

Comment: I don't have a constructor though. This is a static method on a class being called. If you check the Calls.js, you'll see where I"m calling it from.

Comment: So you want to call `TestStore.js` constructor in the static method of `CALLS`, correct?

Comment: TestStore is a singleton. I'm calling the TestAction updateTest and passing in a callback. I need that callback to be passed in as an arg and then called when setState completes.

Comment: Looking at this further, and the only way I could do that would be to somehow override reflux to wait until all listening components return back from their own setStates before firing a callback. Seems a bit much. I believe I can just pass down the value. It's a bit spaghetti code-like, but I don't see another way around it.

Comment: I'll try to figure out something soon.

Comment: Updated the answer, listening to the callback.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that will fire right after the method is called correct? It will not, however, fire after the state is set. The issue I'm finding is a method directly after this.setState that uses the store's state fires before the async setState is completed, thus meaning the old state is used before the new state has been updated.

Comment: I've added the callbacks based on the promises, it should be working now.

Comment: Your suggestion is the correct way to approach this problem, generally, but in my specific case, this still won't work as it still doesn't guarantee the state is actually set prior to the callback being hit. With Reflux, there is no way currently to guarantee that as there is no way to callback after setState is fully complete or to properly use promises.

Comment: Yes, it cant be exactly guaranteed, that the state is set, their `async actions` are still in development mode

Comment: I've added a description of why my case is currently "unsolvable" and a suggestion on what a solution would be, if it is implemented at some point. I've also marked your answer correct, as that is the Reflux suggested way to deal with setState, although it doesn't exactly solve my issue.

Comment: Yea, thank you very much. Hope that they implement their async behaviour soon, otherwise you may try migrating to redux

Comment: I've opened an issue specific to setState callbacks matching React and placed it in the description above if you have anything you'd like to add to it.